# Modal popup doesn't work in a dropdown menu of a table

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want to put a Bootstrap (v3) Modal view in my dropdown menu of a table, but it doesn't work. When I press the Delete button of dropdown menu, the screen darkens a few seconds, but it doesn't pop up the modal view.

If I copy my modal code to another page for testing, it works successfully.

The table data comes from the backend with node.js.
If you need more information, you can tell me.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover,
.dropdown-content a:focus {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,
.dropdown:focus .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
.dropdown:focus .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <td class="td1" style="border-bottom:#979797 solid 1px;">
      <div class="dropdown" style="float: left">
        <a href="#"><img src="/images/dots.png"></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0">
          <form action="/editProInfo" method="POST" novalidate>
            <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<%= ProInfoList[j].Id %>" />
            <button class="dropbtn" style="background-color:transparent; border:0; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: -35px;">
                <a>Edit</a>
              </button>
          </form>
          <button href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="dropbtn" style="background-color:transparent; border:0;margin-bottom: -10px"> 
            <a>Delete</a>
          </button>
          <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Do you want to delete ?</p>
                  <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see one error in your code, change button `href` to `data-target`. This may solve your problem.

Replace this line:

```
 <button href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="dropbtn" style="background-color:transparent; border:0;margin-bottom: -10px"><a>Delete</a></button>
```

with

```
 <button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="dropbtn" style="background-color:transparent; border:0;margin-bottom: -10px">Delete</button>
```

`data-target="#myModal"` points to the id of the modal.

Comment: Thank for your help!  Besides the problem you found, I found the source "bootstrap.min.js"  loaded two times. Now, My code work completely :).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar kind of issues.

Kindly check your script. The dark screen comes for few seconds and disappears due to the code being duplicated.

Sometimes, we keep the code both in HTML file under script tag and also in js file which causes the function runs twice.

Comment: Yes, sometimes only a few error codes cause big trouble.